# SQL string comparision using IF

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, if-statement

This may be a silly question, but can anyone explain why SQL returns `'False'` for

```
IF 'test' = ' test' -- notice leading space
 SELECT 'True'
ELSE
 SELECT 'False'
```

but returns `'True'` for

```
IF 'test' = 'test ' -- notice trailing space
 SELECT 'True'
ELSE
 SELECT 'False'
```

Edit:

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: are u using mysql or another db?

Comment: +1 Not silly, interesting actually :)

Comment: I would consider this as a BUG  :)

Comment: @MaheswaranRavisankar this is not a bug ;) trailing spaces are ignored, but not leading

Comment: I understand that it ignores, I say it can't be that way!

Comment: @Melon I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trailing spaces are ignored.

If you want to really test whether they're the same, so something like this:

```
DECLARE @foo nvarchar(50) = 'foo'
DECLARE @foo2 nvarchar(50) = 'foo ' -- trailing space

IF @foo = @foo2 AND DATALENGTH(@foo) = DATALENGTH(@foo2) --LEN ignores trailing spaces
    SELECT 'true'
ELSE
    SELECT 'false'
```

WHY your example is true:

http://www.timvw.be/2013/04/27/the-curious-case-of-trailing-spaces-in-sql/

As per http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/shadow/sql/sql1992.txt:

> ```
>  3) The comparison of two character strings is determined as fol-
>         lows:
>
>         a) If the length in characters of X is not equal to the length
>           in characters of Y, then the shorter string is effectively
>           replaced, for the purposes of comparison, with a copy of
>           itself that has been extended to the length of the longer
>           string by concatenation on the right of one or more pad char-
>           acters, where the pad character is chosen based on CS. If
>           CS has the NO PAD attribute, then the pad character is an
>           implementation-dependent character different from any char-
>           acter in the character set of X and Y that collates less
>           than any string under CS. Otherwise, the pad character is a
>           .
>
>         b) The result of the comparison of X and Y is given by the col-
>           lating sequence CS.
>
>         c) Depending on the collating sequence, two strings may com-
>           pare as equal even if they are of different lengths or con-
>           tain different sequences of characters. When the operations
>           MAX, MIN, DISTINCT, references to a grouping column, and the
>           UNION, EXCEPT, and INTERSECT operators refer to character
>           strings, the specific value selected by these operations from
>           a set of such equal values is implementation-dependent.
> ```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is controlled with `SET ANSI_PADDING`.

Comment: Little bit hard to put in this comment box, but this: SET ANSI_PADDING ON;


IF 'TEST' = 'TEST '
 SELECT 'true'
ELSE
 SELECT 'false'
ENDIF


SET ANSI_PADDING OFF;


IF 'TEST' = 'TEST '
 SELECT 'true'
ELSE
 SELECT 'false'
ENDIF still yields true true

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is because the database truncates trailing spaces, but not leading spaces.

Some [documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626) to support that guess.

> SQL Server follows the ANSI/ISO SQL-92 specification (Section 8.2,
>   , General rules #3) on how to compare strings
>   with spaces. The ANSI standard requires padding for the character
>   strings used in comparisons so that their lengths match before
>   comparing them. The padding directly affects the semantics of WHERE
>   and HAVING clause predicates and other Transact-SQL string
>   comparisons. For example, Transact-SQL considers the strings 'abc' and
>   'abc ' to be equivalent for most comparison operations.

Comment: I was awaiting the database platform answer of OP to support that.

Comment: The quoted documentation contradicts your guess, but still a useful answer.